# position of optional arguments

Tags: optional-arguments

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\price}[2][17.5]{\pounds #2 excl VAT @ #1\%}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\price{100} \\
\price[20]{30}


\end{document}
```

Works perfectly fine.

For my purpose, is it possible to change it, so that `\price{30}{20}` works like `\price[20]{30}`. That is, I want the optional arguments to be **after** the first argument and uses `{}` brackets.

Thanks.

Comment: you can change the order and use `{}` but then you can't really (well you can but you shouldn't)  make the argument optional. With normal arguments  `\price 2 3` is (due to basic tex rules) the same as `\price{2}{3}`  so it is pretty odd to make `\price{2} 3` not the same as `\price{2}{3}`  If you really want that use xparse and a `g` argument, but it breaks all latex syntax rules.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. It behaves like `\frac12` for `\frac{1}{2}` if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Yes that behaviour is built in to the lowest level of TeX's parser unrelated to any particular macro definition such as `\frac` or  `\price`. You can intercept TeX's normal rules and search for an explicit mandatory `{` character but ....